# Docker container keeps restarting (wikijs)

Tags: docker

I am trying to follow [this article](https://docs.requarks.io/en/install/digitalocean) and set up https for wikijs. However, when I run following command:

```
docker create --name=wiki -e LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN=wiki.mywebsite.com -e 
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com 
-e SSL_ACTIVE=1 -e DB_TYPE=postgres -e DB_HOST=db -e DB_PORT=5432 -e 
DB_PASS_FILE=/etc/wiki/.db-secret -v /etc/wiki/.db-secret:/etc/wiki/.db-secret:ro -e 
DB_USER=wiki -e DB_NAME=wiki -e UPGRADE_COMPANION=1 --restart=unless-stopped -h wiki 
--network=wikinet -p 80:3000 -p 443:3443 requarks/wiki:2
```

and then do docker start wiki, I get docker container that keeps restarting. When I hit docker container logs in my terminal, I get following output:

```
Loading configuration from /wiki/config.yml... OK
DB_PASS_FILE is defined. Will use secret from file.
>>> Failed to read Docker Secret File using path defined in DB_PASS_FILE env 
variable!
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

I am stuck here and can't figure out any solution. Help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the file `/etc/wiki/.db-secret` exist on your host? If it is missing, Docker will create it as a directory (and then mount the directory as requested at `/etc/wiki/.db-secret` inside the container). That would cause the "illegal operation on a directory" error.

Comment: Using `docker create` is kind of unusual; it creates a container in a not-especially-useful stopped state, though that seems secondary to your question.  Do you have the image's Dockerfile or any other source code required for a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem. This is how I fixed it:

- To list all (even stopped) containers: `docker container ls -a`
- I killed (deleted) the defunct ones ('db' and 'wiki' itself)

`docker stop $id`

`docker container rm $id`

- Then I recreated the 'db' container, but with

`-v /etc/wiki:/etc/wiki:ro` instead of
`-v /etc/wiki/.db-secret:/etc/wiki/.db-secret:ro`

- Then I recreated the 'wiki' container in the same way
- Afterwards I started the 'db' container: `docker container start $id`
- And then the 'wiki' container in the same way

Maybe the Wiki.js docs are wrong. It seems docker wants a directory to share between the host and the container, but the Wiki.js docs suggest only sharing the .db-secret file itself.

Comment: In my case the it was because I was trying to read from another directory that I guess Docker couldn't access. When I moved files back into /etc/wiki everything worked.

Comment: It was very easy to make a pull request for that, I beat you to it it seems : https://github.com/requarks/wiki-docs/pull/61 . As an additional issue I had the file did not exist but was a folder ( because of copying and not checking output ). I updated the docs to reflect that and it works for me now. If anyone else finds things, please feel free to make a pull request and become a contributor :)!